# Matlab: multiple imputation for missing data

Tags: matlab, statistics, missing-data

Is there any package available for [multiple imputation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imputation_%28statistics%29#Multiple_imputation)? Or any reference I can use to write my own function? Since the percentage of missing data is really high in some columns of the data (approximately 50–70%), I think multiple imputation is a good choice.

Comment: Could you do something like [interp1](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html)?

Answer (score 1):

If you installed [Bioinformatics Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/knnimpute.html), check `knnimpute` for more details. It is used to impute missing data using nearest-neighbor method.